# News feed. Best way to store info

Tags: android

I'm doing a news feed in android, and to make it work faster and avoid download the same info many times, I need a way to store strings to title, url, pub_date, and the image of each post, from different sites and later be able to organize them per date. So what would be the recommended way to save this info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be no single correct answer to your question. But I would go with implementing a content provider that would be backing the caching of your feeds in a local SQLite database.

You might be interested to watch

[Google I/O 2010 - Android REST client applications](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE)

Comment: Actually, I've made a sqlite database, and I was going that way until the point I  realize I would  need a  content provider to use with the cursorloader, what made think if there wasn't a simpler/better way to do it. Thanks for the video, I'll watch it now.